# Maximum sum subarray, C++, DSA

Tags: c++

**I had tried to write a program to find the maximum sum subarray, I am able to take the output correctly in a certain scenario but if I want to change it the output is not as desired. So anyone can help me?**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int minValue,n;

    int a[n]={4,-2,-3,4,-1,-2,1,5,-3};

    int max_so_far = minValue;

    int max_ending_here=0;

    int start=0, end=0, s=0;

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){

        max_ending_here = max_ending_here+a[i];

        if(max_so_far < max_ending_here){

            max_so_far = max_ending_here;

            start=s;

            end = i;

        }

        if(max_ending_here<0){

            max_ending_here=0;

            s = i+1;

        }

        start=s;

    }
    cout<<"maximum sum subarray is: "<<max_so_far;
    cout<<"\nstart "<<start;
    //cout<<"\nend "<<end;
    return 0;
}
```

**The output of this code is:**

*maximum sum subarray is: 7*

*start 3*

**But if I try to print the value of end as well as shown in the following program:**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int minValue,n;

    int a[n]={4,-2,-3,4,-1,-2,1,5,-3};

    int max_so_far = minValue;

    int max_ending_here=0;

    int start=0, end=0, s=0;

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)

    {

        max_ending_here = max_ending_here+a[i];

        if(max_so_far < max_ending_here){

            max_so_far = max_ending_here;

            start=s;

            end = i;

        }

        if(max_ending_here<0){

            max_ending_here=0;

            s = i+1;

        }

        start=s;

    }

    cout<<"maximum sum subarray is: "<<max_so_far;

    cout<<"\nstart "<<start;

    cout<<"\nend "<<end;

    return 0;

}
```

**The output becomes as:**

*maximum sum subarray is: 32760*

*start 3*

*end 0*

**Can anybody point out the actual error for me?**

Comment: `int minValue,n; int a[n]={4,-2,-3,4,-1,-2,1,5,-3};` is a bug. What value did you set `n` to be before a is created? Also VLAs are not part of standard `c++`

Comment: How can I correct it, sir?

Comment: `int a[]={4,-2,-3,4,-1,-2,1,5,-3}; int minValue,n = std::size(a);`

Comment: still, I am not getting the right answer, sir.

Comment: maximum sum subarray is: 1884970409
start 23
end 20

maximum sum subarray is: 131373
start 29

Comment: `int max_so_far = minValue;` is a bug. `minValue` was not initialized to any value. It's undefined behavior to use a variables value without initializing it.

Comment: So, What statement should I use to remove the bug?

Comment: I am not sure what the purpose of minValue is so I am not sure how to suggest initializing  it to a proper value.  It could be `int max_so_far = a[0];` or `int max_so_far = std::numeric_limts<int>::min();` but not sure from the algorithm if this makes sense.

Comment: should i initialize max_so_far=0  ? , sir

Comment: It could also be `int max_so_far = std::numeric_limts<int>::min();` to assign it to the smallest possible int. The documentation for that is here: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Comment: okay, sir. Along with my problem, I got to know about some bugs in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made 2 changes:

1. Used INT_MIN
2. Used vector instead of array definition.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<int> a ={4,-2,-3,4,-1,-2,1,5,-3}; // <------------ here
    
    int minValue=INT_MIN, n= a.size(); // <--------- here


    int max_so_far = minValue;

    int max_ending_here=0;

    int start=0, end=0, s=0;

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)

    {

        max_ending_here = max_ending_here+a[i];

        if(max_so_far < max_ending_here){

            max_so_far = max_ending_here;

            start=s;

            end = i;

        }

        if(max_ending_here<0){

            max_ending_here=0;

            s = i+1;

        }

        start=s;

    }

    cout<<"maximum sum subarray is: "<<max_so_far;

    cout<<"\nstart "<<start;

    cout<<"\nend "<<end;

    return 0;

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
maximum sum subarray is: 7
start 3
end 7
```